Number of parameters in BERT model
Suppose you are pretraining a BERT model with 8 layers, 768-dim hidden states, 8 attention heads, and a sub-word vocabulary of size 40k. Also, your feed-forward hidden layer is of dimension 3072. What will be the number of parameters of the model? You can ignore the bias terms, and other parameters used corresponding to the final loss computation from the final encoder representation. The BERT model can take at most 512 tokens in the input.

This looks like homework from a course...

@SilentCloud it is, indeed. The question is verbatim from an assignment for an ongoing AI/ML course.
